# Jackson: Deserializing String Reader is failing

Tags: string, deserialization, jackson-databind

I am using Jakcson Databind v2.9.9. I have following code that fails.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String test = "test";
        Reader inputString = new StringReader(test);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Object o = objectMapper.readValue(inputString, objectMapper.constructType(SimpleType.construct(String.class)));
        System.out.println("Output: " + o);
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'test': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2853)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2831)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._matchToken2(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2628)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._matchToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2606)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._matchTrue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:725)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3063)
    at com.feign.orch.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Any help please?

Comment: It may be due to the fact that ```test``` does not match a valid JSON format

Comment: I have similar requirement to hit rest end point that returns String. It works fine when used with SpringBoot, but fails on using Feign Client. I ended up writing a test above to test it and it fails.